# Composition of partial functions to reduce code length

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I want to compose a functions in a specific way to reduce code length

For instance composing a simple add function as such :

```scala
    val add3 = (a: Int, b:Int) => (c:Int) => a+b+c

    val composed = (a:Int, b:Int) => n:add3(a, b) => n(1) + n(2) + n(3)
```

That would be very useful so that I don't have to pass **a** and **b** as parameters every time.

Is there a way of doing that in Scala ?

Comment: I am sorry, I really tired to formulate a helpful question here, but the only thing I could come up with was this: huh?

Comment: I can't disagree with @Dima ... If you want to reduce code length at this point, you have to get a compiling and running code and *then* refactor it: *make it work* and **then** *make it clean* . You know...

Comment: Also, partial functions are too abstract to most unfamiliar people to not use related scala specific terms to explain your problem first like *method* , *currying* , *closure*... Most of the time, learning using them, would definitively help you out. Well, it worked for me at some point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by these notations, like @Dima... But, I've been through this kind of ... trying to handle partial function by writing down intuitive way to... comprehend them? Is that what you're doing? So I'll try to interpret you step by step.

## First, we have to be clear about `add3`

This code you give, maybe just as scratch to understand I guess, won't compile in scala:

> ```
> val add3 = (a: Int, b:Int)(c:Int) => a+b+c
> ```

Indeed, we get in a REPL:

> error: not a legal formal parameter. Note: Tuples cannot be directly
>   destructured in method or function parameters.
>         Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
>         or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
>          val add3 = (a: Int, b:Int)(c:Int) => a+b+c
>                                    ^

But I may have got the idea you wanted to suggest...

`add3` is either a method like:

```
def add3Method (a: Int, b:Int)(c:Int) = a+b+c
```

which can be then partially applied:

```
val add3 = add3Method _
```

Or it can directly be a function like:

```
val add3 = (a: Int, b:Int) => (c: Int) => a+b+c
```

Either way, it give a function of type `(Int, Int) => Int => Int`. **Is that what you want?**

## Then we have to be clear about "`composed`"

This code you give, maybe just as scratch to understand I guess, won't compile in scala *neither*:

> ```
> val composed = (a:Int, b:Int) => n:add3(a, b) => n(1) + n(2) + n(3)
> ```

But I may... Well, at least, might have got the idea you wanted to suggest *too*...

### (a) closure?

The way you express it make me think is like a closure which would mean ultimately that `composed` has a type `(Int, Int) => Int`. **Is that what you meant?**

### (b) a function which takes kind of a `add3`?

Or, you just want `add3` to be just any function of the same type to pass to `composed` I assume is `(Int, Int) => Int => Int`. **Is that what you meant?**

## Then, you have some ways to define "`composed`"

Either by mapping or by an intermediate variable.

### closure, intermediate variable way

```
val composedCI = (a:Int, b:Int) => { val n = add3(a,b); n(1) + n(2) + n(3)}
```

### closure, mapping way

```
val composedCM = (a:Int, b:Int) => (1 to 3).map(add3(a,b)).sum
```

### taking as argument `add3`, intermediate variable way

```
val composedTI = (a:Int, b:Int) => (myAdd3asAnArg: (Int, Int) => Int => Int) => { val n = myAdd3asAnArg(a,b); n(1) + n(2) + n(3) }
```

### taking as argument `add3`, mapping way

```
val composedTM = (a:Int, b:Int) => (myAdd3asAnArg: (Int, Int) => Int => Int) => (1 to 3).map(myAdd3asAnArg(a,b)).sum
```

## Using "`composed`"

```
println(composedCM(4,5))
println(composedCI(4,5))
println(composedTM(4,5)(add3))
println(composedTI(4,5)(add3))
```

Will give

```
33
33
33
33
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: The closure mapping  way is exactly was I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: Great! Would you mind marking the answer as correct then @nbreizh ? With that done, I'll edit your question for clarity whenever it is possible. ( cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow#answer-147532 )

Answer (score 3):

I'm also uncertain what exactly you mean, but this is how you can create a function that takes:

- g: a function taking two or three ints, that returns an int (this would be `add3` in your example)
- f: a function taking one int, that returns an int (this would be `n` in your example)

and returns:

- another function g(f), taking the same inputs as g, but first applying f

```
// type aliases
type TwoOrThreeIntFn = (Int, Int) => Int => Int
type OneIntFn = Int => Int

// create a function that takes two functions and returns their composition
def composition(f: OneIntFn)(g: TwoOrThreeIntFn):TwoOrThreeIntFn = { (a:Int, b:Int) => (c:Int) =>  g(f(a), f(b))(f(c)) }
```